# Getting rid of text labels on overlayed px.bar plots

Tags: express, plotly, label

I have successfully plotted five bar charts (all with the same x-axis) vertically, one on top of the other.  Each chart separately represents the time occurrence of different variables (identified by long Key Phrases) during the same period.  I have used px.bar with barmode = 'overlay' and facet_row = "Key_phrases".  The routine insists on writing the "Key_phrases" vertically on the the right hand border in addition to the legend, but the phrases as so long that they overlap one another.  How can I turn this off and write each phrase, horizontally inside its individual plot?

Comment: Can you include the code you used to generate your bar charts, and a screenshot of the bar chart you're getting? This will help clarify your question a bit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- **plotly express** creates an **annotation** for each row of traces in a facetted figure
- have created some sample data that generates a long *KeyPhrase*
- generate a figure in way you describe
- demonstrated overriding annotation text.  Another option would be remove the annotations

```
phrase = "The COP26 summit will bring parties together to accelerate action towards the goals of the Paris Agreement and the UN Framework Convention on Climate Change "

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Key_phrases": np.repeat(
            [" ".join(phrase.split(" ")[5 * p : 5 * (p + 1)]) for p in range(5)], 4
        ),
        "x": np.tile(range(5), 4),
        "y": np.random.uniform(1, 4, 20),
    }
)

fig = px.bar(df, x="x", y="y", facet_row="Key_phrases")
fig.show()

# override annotation text
fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        {**a, **{"text": f"phr.{i+1}"}}
        for i, a in enumerate(fig.to_dict()["layout"]["annotations"])
    ]
)
```

Comment: Rob, you answered my question completely.  Thanks! This was something that I could not find in any of the documentations.  And it begs the next question: in the example you provide above,  how can I take the label phrases and write them instead inside each graph box instead of the external legend labels.  When I use the "annotate" option, it only puts the phrase in the last (bottom) box.  I have found examples that annotate all the graphs with the same annotations, but  I can't figure out how to annotate each of the boxes individually.